# Nvidia 410m - No backlight

Tags: nvidia, backlight

I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, a Sony Vaio VCGEP33F, but a few days ago I began using Nvidia drivers (331.79) This laptop also has an Intel integrated GPU, but I have disabled it in the BIOS, and so long the OS has not noticed it.

My question is the following, since I started using Nvidia drivers, sometimes as I boot up the computer, after GRUB (I have windows 8 installed along Ubuntu) the screen will go black, with no backlight and so it will stay. May I flash a light at the screen I can see it'working, I can login, but cannot see crap.

If I reboot the computer several times (Itś random, and between 3 or 7) sometimes I see a nvidia logo and that is when the backlight will be on, else I will be stuck with no backlight at all. Then, if I connect a display to the VGA output during boot and disconnect it after logging in the laptop's screen will be on.

I've been researching on the issue,but have not found anything like this, many people need to use bumblebee, me nope as I disabled the other GPU, many people have no brightness cntrol, which I have if the screen is on.

Although annoying, I said it solves itself but I would like to know how to fix this! thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching more into the issue, and I have provided myself with a poor solution, but I will share it here in case it helps others.

If after the login sound I type my password, and then press the (Fn)+F5 key (Brightness control hotkey) the screen will light up as normal.

I still find it most annoying not seeing the beautiful lockscreen and/or having my computer usable from start.

Does anyone know a way to make a startup script that changes brightness before login?